# PHP ActiveRecord - find_by_sql + include

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord

I need to use a custom query with PHP ActiveRecord as I need a `UNION` statement, even though I'm querying the same table on both queries. I wanna be able to include onto the result the columns I have as `belongs_to` on my model.

Here's my model code:

```
class FeedActivity extends MyModel {

    static $table_name = 'feed_activity';

    static $belongs_to = array(
        array('user_reference', 'class_name' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 'user_reference_id'),
        array('follow', 'class_name' => 'Follow', 'foreign_key' => 'follow_id'),
        array('challenge_user', 'class_name' => 'ChallengeUser', 'foreign_key' => 'challenge_user_id'),
    );
}
```

And my query:

```
$list = FeedActivity::find_by_sql('
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            feed_activity
        WHERE
            challenge_user_id IS NOT NULL
    )

    UNION ALL

    (
        SELECT
            feed_activity.*
        FROM
            feed_activity
        JOIN
            follow ON follow.id_follower = ' .(int) $user_id . '
                    AND follow.id = feed_activity.follow_id
        WHERE
            follow_id IS NOT NULL
        LIMIT 0, 5
    )

    ORDER BY created_at DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10

');
```

Any thoughts on how I could acomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a good night of sleep I found a quick and easy solution. I implemented the following method to `MyModel` (superclass of all my models):

```
public static function find_by_sql_including($sql, $include = null)
{
    return static::table()->find_by_sql($sql, null, true, $include);
}
```

Now I do something like this for querying:

```
FeedActivity::find_by_sql($sql, array('user_reference','follow','user_challenge'));
```